# Galois theory question (Kummer's Theory)

Tags: galois-theory

This question is from a past exam paper.

Suppose $E = \mathbb{Q}(\theta)$, where $\theta$ is a root of $X^{3} - 39X + 26 \in \mathbb{Q}[X]$.

1. Prove that $E$ is cyclic Galois extension of $\mathbb{Q}$, but there ir no $A \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $E = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{A})$.
2. Prove that there is $B \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})$ such that $E(\sqrt{-3}) = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})(\sqrt[3]{B})$ and find this B.

Ok, 1. since the polynomial is irreducible, the extension has degree 3 over $\mathbb{Q}$ and thus the group is cyclic. Now I can use analysis and show that the polynomial has 3 real roots and conclude that such A cannot exist. (though perhaps there is another way, in a more algebraic way, the quadratic resolvent is too complicated for this case, see below)

2. Since $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{-3})$ has a a $3$rd root of unity, then such $B$ exists. The problem is, how can I find this $B$? I know the way is using the Lagrange Resolvent, but for this I need to know the group $Gal(E(\sqrt{-3})/\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3}))$. I know it has 3 elements but I cannot find a generator since using the quadratic resolvent to find the roots of the polynomial I find such complicated roots like $\sqrt[3]{13-13\sqrt{14}} + \sqrt[3]{13+13\sqrt{14}}$.

Comment: in 1. you need also to check that the discriminant is a square. There should be faster methods to solve 2., but in principle $B=(a+\omega b+\omega^2c)^3$ ($a,b,c$ the roots of your polynomial, $\omega$ the 3rd root of unity) is computable.

Comment: In addition, an expansion of $(a + \omega b + \omega^2 c)^3$ will contain an expression for the square root of the discriminant, so you need to know this value explicitly to compute $B$.

Comment: How did you see that $E/\Bbb{Q}$ is Galois?